# JQuery find parent element or find

Tags: jquery

how can I find the active (this) class called: `.item-name` ?
since these items are dynamic I'm using `.find` but I think i need to add a `.parent()` in here somewhere.

`$(this).find('.item-name').val(customers.product);`

HTML:

```
<tr class="item-row">
              <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_name[]">Hourly Rate</textarea>
              <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
              <a class="add-product" href="javascript:;" title="Add Product">O</a>
              </div></td>
              <td class="description"><textarea form ="testinsert" name="item_desc[]">Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="cost" form ="testinsert" name="item_cost[]">$150.00</textarea></td>
              <td><textarea class="qty" form ="testinsert" name="item_qty[]">3</textarea></td>
              <td><span class="price" form ="testinsert" name="item_price[]">$450.00</span></td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                    var customers;
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                            customers = this;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    $(this).find('.item-name').val(customers.product);
                    $(this).find('.item-desc').val(customers.disc);
}
```

UPDATE (populates **ALL** product and desc):

```
$('.add-product').click(function(){
//$('.add-product').live('click',function(){
// **************************************
    $("#productdiv").css("display", "block");

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'product_fill.php',                         
        data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){
            populateSelectBoxes($('#productdiv #ddproduct'), data);

            function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
                var products = [];
                $.each(data, function() {
                    products.push('<li data-value="'+this.autonum+'">' + this.product + '</li>');
                });
                $select.append(products.join(''));
            }

            function populateTableRow($addProduct, data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                var customers;
                $.each(data, function() {
                    if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                        customers = this;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                $addProduct.parents().find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);
                $addProduct.parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_desc']").val(customers.disc);
                $addProduct.parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_cost']").val(customers.rate);

            }

            $('#productdiv #ddproduct li').click(function(e) {
                var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
                populateTableRow($('.add-product'), data, selection);
                $('ul').empty();
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: `.find('.item-name')` will indeed find all matching descendant elements.  Though you're trying to set the *value* (`.val()`) of a `td` element, which *has no* value.  It's also not clear what `this` refers to in those lines, so where are you even conducting this search?

Comment: I'm trying to add to the textarea with name=item_name[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in `populateTableRow()` function to update elements in the same  as has the anchor that was clicked to trigger the $('.add-product').live('click'... event handler.

The solution way to just create a variable in the scope of that click handler and reference it from within populateTableRow()

added the `var clickedRow` in the correct scope:

```
$('.add-product').live('click',function(){

var clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr");  // <--- ADD THIS PART

$("#productdiv").css("display", "block");

$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'product_fill.php',                         
  data: {action:"invoice"},                                             
  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data){
    populateSelectBoxes($('#productdiv #ddproduct'), data);

    function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
        var products = [];
        $.each(data, function() {
            products.push('<li data-value="'+this.autonum+'">' + this.product + '</li>');
        });
        $select.append(products.join(''));
    }

    function populateTableRow(data, selectedCustomerAutonum) {
        var customers;
        $.each(data, function() {
            if (this.autonum == selectedCustomerAutonum) {
                customers = this;
                return false;
            }
        });
        clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);
        clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_desc']").val(customers.disc);
        clickedRow.find("textarea[name^='item_cost']").val(customers.rate);
    }

    $('#productdiv #ddproduct li').click(function(e) {
        var selection = $(this).attr("data-value");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
        populateTableRow(data, selection);
        $('ul').empty();
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
                $(this).find('.item-name').val(customers.product);
                $(this).find('.item-desc').val(customers.disc);
```

are finding all elements with class name of `item-name` and `item-desc` (i.e. `<textarea class="item-name">` which you do not have in your HTML. You need to target on `name` attribute which would match.

```
                $(this).find("textarea[name^='item-name']").val(customers.product);
                $(this).find("textarea[name^='item-desc']").val(customers.disc);
```

Hard to pinpoint based on the code you show, but, you probably also need to use `$tableBody.find()` instead of `$(this).find()` because in this scope, `$(this)` is probably empty.

Comment: Ok:  $('.item-name').find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product); populates every row and $(this).find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product); does nothing?

Comment: How are you calling `populateTableRow()` elsewhere in your code? How do you reference it, can you show the full call including parameters (ie everything between `()`)?

Comment: got it working:  `$('.add-product').parents('.item-row').find("textarea[name^='item_name']").val(customers.product);`

Comment: thought it was fixed until added `<a>` to dynamic rows - now all the rows get the selected click. - SEE UPDATE in original question.

Comment: @BarclayVision can I see the rest of your HTML? Like, where is `#productdiv #ddproduct` ?